# How do you generate random strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, random

I am looking for methods to generate random strings in C++.Here is my code:

```
string randomStrGen(int length) {
    static string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    string result;
    result.resize(length);

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];

    return result;
}
```

But the `seed(time(NULL))` is not random enough.Are there any other better way to generate random strings in C++?

Comment: Could you please explain 'not random enough'?

Comment: @Bobby:It is becuase my wrong use of srand that the produced random string would be same if calling the function within a short time interval.

Comment: 'not random enough' - then you can sleep(1) e.g.  . but naturally, it's very bad idea, 'cause obviously you cannot wait too long. but nevertheless it's still idea

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't call `srand()` on each function call - only call it once at first function call or program startup. You migh want to have a flag indicating whether`srand()` has already been called.

The sugested method is good except that you misuse `srand()` and get predictably bad results.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. One problem with such a flag is that another function that requires random numbers, but using a different flag, will cause problems too. I think it's best if functions needing random numbers just get random numbers, and are decoupled from the generator initialisation. Really, seeding should just be done at the top of `main`. :-)

Comment: Or use the re-entrant versions with their own seed

Comment: @fa: True, that stops generators from stepping on each other, but, if these different functions are all initially run too closely together, you still run into the same problem.

Comment: Re-Using seed values is a bad idea. If you must build your own rand function that calls srand() the first time through (returning the result of rand()).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/libs/random). It uses a different generator than the one provided with most standard libraries, that should be more robust.

In specific, most standard libraries provide linear congruential generators, which don't perform very well when you `mod` their results with small numbers. Boost.Random has a Mersenne twister generator.

As sharptooth says, though (good spotting!), only seed the generator once, at the very start of your program. Seeding it every time you want something random is counter-productive.

Comment: Not only seeding on each call is counter-productive but if the function is called repeatedly without a long enough delay it will produce identical results.

Comment: Exactly. Really, it'd be best for libraries to do what Perl does in this regard, and do the initialisation itself (with a sensible seed of course) if the program itself hasn't done so. I mean, it's too late for that now, in that standard C libraries can't do it without violating the standard, but you know what I mean. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface to get a random number in this site http://www.random.org/ and you will be sure to get a real random number! But if you are looking for performance...

Answer (score 0):

On unix systems you can read random values from the file `/dev/random`

Comment: Unless you're using the numbers for cryptographic purposes, reading straight off `/dev/random` (except to use as a seed to another PRNG) is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use the standard library, then you can do something like this:

```
<somewhere else>
srand(NULL);
</somewhere else>

char get_rand_char() {
  static string charset(...);
  return charset[rand() % charset.size()];
}

std::string generate_random_string(size_t n) {
  char rbuf[n];
  std::generate(rbuf, rbuf+n, &get_rand_char);
  return std::string(rbuf, n);
}
```

This code is naturally more modular, and standard library maintainers tend to write better code than me.  This way I can change the random character generating part of the code without touching anything else.  I could even forward to a function that randomly picks a random number generator!  Not that it would compound the randomness or anything...

Answer (score 0):

use std::generate_n. This way you can specify the length of your generated string. In the below case its 4.

```
std::string uniqueName() {
    auto randchar = []() -> char
    {
        const char charset[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1);
        return charset[ rand() % max_index ];
    };
    std::string str(4,0);
    std::generate_n( str.begin(), 4, randchar );
    return str;
}
```