# How to generate 'consecutive' c++ strings?

Tags: c++, string, random

I would like to generate consecutive C++ strings like e.g. in cameras: IMG001, IMG002 etc. being able to indicate the prefix and the string length.

I have found a solution where I can generate random strings from concrete character set: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146792/how-do-you-generate-random-strings-in-c)

But I cannot find the thing I want to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string make_string(const std::string& a_prefix,
                        size_t a_suffix,
                        size_t a_max_length)
{
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << a_prefix <<
              std::setfill('0') <<
              std::setw(a_max_length - a_prefix.length()) <<
              a_suffix;
    return result.str();
}

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << make_string("IMG", i, 6) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/HZWmtI.

Comment: +1 for using string stream, which is typesafe and secure than sprintf approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>


std::string GetNextNumber( int &lastNum )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "IMG";
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << lastNum++;

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    std::string s = GetNextNumber( x );
    s = GetNextNumber( x );


    return 0;
}
```

You can call `GetNextNumber` repeatedly with an int reference to generate new image numbers. You can always use `sprintf` but it won't be the c++ way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 const int max_size = 7 + 1; // maximum size of the name plus one 
 char buf[max_size];
 for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; ++i) {
   sprintf(buf, "IMG%.04d", i);
   printf("The next name is %s\n", buf);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char * seq_gen(char * prefix) {
    static int counter;
    char * result;
    sprintf(result, "%s%03d", prefix, counter++);
    return result;
}
```

This would print your prefix with 3 digit padding string. If you want a lengthy string, all you have to do is provide the prefix as much as needed and change the **%03d** in the above code to whatever length of digit padding you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the idea is rather simple. Just store the current number and increment it each time new string is generated. You can implement it to model an iterator to reduce the fluff in using it (you can then use standard algorithms with it). Using Boost.Iterator (it should work with any string type, too):

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

// can't come up with a better name
template <typename StringT, typename OrdT>
struct ordinal_id_generator : boost::iterator_facade<
    ordinal_id_generator<StringT, OrdT>, StringT,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag, StringT
> {
    ordinal_id_generator(
        const StringT& prefix = StringT(),
        typename StringT::size_type suffix_length = 5, OrdT initial = 0
    ) : prefix(prefix), suffix_length(suffix_length), ordinal(initial)
    {}
private:
    StringT prefix;
    typename StringT::size_type suffix_length;
    OrdT ordinal;

    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() {
        ++ordinal;
    }

    bool equal(const ordinal_id_generator& other) const {
        return (
               ordinal == other.ordinal
            && prefix == other.prefix
            && suffix_length == other.suffix_length
        );
    }

    StringT dereference() const {
        std::basic_ostringstream<typename StringT::value_type> ss;
        ss << prefix << std::setfill('0')
           << std::setw(suffix_length) << ordinal;
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

And example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

typedef ordinal_id_generator<std::string, unsigned> generator;

int main() {
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out(std::cout, "\n");

    std::copy_n(generator("IMG"), 5, out);
    // can even behave as a range
    std::copy(generator("foo", 1, 2), generator("foo", 1, 4), out);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the standard library's string streams. Have an integer that you increment, and insert into the string stream after every increment. To control the string length, there's the concept of fill characters, and the width() member function.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways of doing that.

The generic one would be to, like the link that you showed, have an array of possible characters. Then after each iteration, you start from right-most character, increment it (that is, change it to the next one in the possible characters list) and if it overflowed, set it to the first one (index 0) and go the one on the left. This is exactly like incrementing a number in base, say 62.

In your specific example, you are better off with creating the string from another string and a number.

If you like `*printf`, you can write a string with `"IMG%04d"` and have the parameter go from 0 to whatever.

If you like `stringstream`, you can similarly do so.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by consecutive strings ?

Since you've mentioned that you're using C++ strings, try using the `.string::append` method.

```
string str, str2;
str.append("A");
str.append(str2);
```

Lookup http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/ for more overloaded calls of the append function.

Comment: Underneath the main header of the question, there's a little section that has additional details.  Is your browser not displaying that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a counter that is increased everytime you get a new name. This counter has to be saved when your application is ends, and loaded when you application starts.

Could be something like this:

```
class NameGenerator
{
public:
    NameGenerator()
        : m_counter(0)
        {
            // Code to load the counter from a file
        }

    ~NameGenerator()
        {
            // Code to save the counter to a file
        }

    std::string get_next_name()
        {
            // Combine your preferred prefix with your counter
            // Increase the counter
            // Return the string
        }

private:
    int m_counter;
}

NameGenerator my_name_generator;
```

Then use it like this:

```
std::string my_name = my_name_generator.get_next_name();
```

Comment: suggested improvement : we can only call the function *get_name()* once before the returned value change. Let's call it *get_next_name()* to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

it's pseudo code. you'll understand what i mean :D

```
int counter = 0, retval;
do
{
char filename[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(filename, "IMG00%d", counter++);
if(retval = CreateFile(...))
//ok, return
}while(!retval);
```