# Open Sequential Files C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a folder full of files in this format FileName000.extension FileName001.extension etc.
I need to open them all and do something in C++.
What I've tried is this:

```
for(int i=0; i<number_of_files; i++){
        char filename[64];
if(i<10){
        sprintf(filename, "/Path/To/File/FileName00%i.extension", i);
}
    if(i<100){
        sprintf(filename, "/Path/To/File/FileName0%i.extension", i);
}
else{
        sprintf(filename, "/Path/To/File/FileName%i.extension", i);
}
        ifstream infile ( filename );

//DO STUFF TO FILES HERE INSIDE THE FOR LOOP
}
```

This doesn't seem to work because of the ifs for some reason
Any help would be appreciated. It doesn't matter if it's a char or a string just that it works. I'm using Xcode as an IDE but the program will have to work on Windows as well.

Comment: why don't you use File *file = fopen(..); ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate 'consecutive' c++ strings ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713643/how-to-generate-consecutive-c-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf(... "...%03d...", ...)` to get a conistent 3-digit number.

Answer (score 2):

If you read a good [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) you will see that you don't need the selective parts at all:

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/Path/To/File/FileName%03d.extension", i);
```

The `3` in the format code tells `snprintf` to use three characters as field width, the leading `0` tells it to use leading zeroes for values less than 99.

---

As for the problems you have with your `if` statements, you are missing an `else`:

```
if (i < 10) { ... }
else if (i < 100) { ... }
else { ... }
```

---

If you want a C++ solution, then you can use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "/Path/To/File/FileName" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i << ".extension";

ifstream file(os.str());
```

Comment: No wonder all programs that support sequential input use the same number format, I thought it was just a sort of meme and they all wrote their own implementations of this...

Does anyone know a good reference for the C standard library functions and features?